# Manipulação de Excel em python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Gostaria de atualizar o excel toda vez que o programa rodar, mas a biblioteca só deixa eu escrever um novo excel, e não atualizar ele.
Como posso fazer isso?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://g1.globo.com/previsao-do-tempo/sp/sao-paulo.ghtml")



soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


days = soup.find(class_ = "forecast-next-days__content")
today = soup.find(class_="columns medium-24 large-12 medium-centered")

nome = [today.find(class_="forecast-header__date").get_text()]

tempmax = today.find(class_="forecast-today__temperature forecast- 
today__temperature--max").get_text()
tempmin = today.find(class_="forecast-today__temperature forecast- 
today__temperature--min").get_text()

tempmax = tempmax[0:4]
tempmin = tempmin[0:4]
temp2 = [tempmax]
temp2 +=[tempmin]




nome += [n.get_text() for n in days.select(".forecast-table .forecast-next- 
days__item-label")]
temp2 += [d.get_text() for d in days.select(".forecast-table .forecast-next-days__item-value")]




temmax = temp2[0:18:2]
temmin = temp2[1:18:2]





tempo = pd.DataFrame({
   "nome": nome,
   "temperatura_max":temmax,
    "temperatura_min":temmin
   })



tempo.to_excel(r"C:\Users\nlsouza\Desktop\python5.xlsx")
```

Comment: Sua pergunta é sobre Pandas, você poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar a tag [tag:pandas]? (e talvez remover a tag `request`, sua pergunta não parece ser sobre isso).. Quanto à pergunta, você não consegue criar um dataframe a partir da planilha existente, editar o dataframe e salvá-lo novamente usando o mesmo método que você usou?

Comment: [Esta pergunta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47738103/1284458) talvez te ajude...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Não é possível "atualizar um arquivo Excel"

Na verdade, o próprio Excel só escreve um novo arquivo de Excel - 
é impossível atualizar dados em um arquvo do tipo usado no Excel - xlsx - "in place".  Primeiro por que quando se fala em manipulação de arquivos, não é possível inserir dados "no meio" de um arquivo, como se inserem linhas em uma planilha. E segundo porque o xlsx é um arquivo binário, zipado - então mesmo que você faça um append no arquivo, até é possível gerar de volta o arquivo XML com o conteúdo de sua planilha ao final do arquivo ZIP - só que esse conteúdo vai ser duplicado: seu .xlsx teria o dobro do tamanho necessário.

O que o Excel e quase todos os outros programas fazem (a exceção podem ser *alguns* editores de PDF, e dependendo da edição feita), é gravar um arquivo novo, e, na sequência, excluir o arquivo antigo e renomear o arquivo novo para ter o mesmo nome do antigo.

Pode parecer um "desperdício" e que "fica lento", mas na ponta do lápis não é o que acontece - um computador moderno pode escrever dados em disco a taxa de (pelo menos) dezenas de megabytes por segundo - e um arquivo de 100MB já seria grande demais para ter qualquer uso prático pelo Excel diretamente, por exemplo.

Se você está falando de milhões de registros, que começariam a ficar pesados nesse modelo, também tem que partir para armazenamento de dados em um banco de dados, e não em um arquivo monolítico como um .xlsx - ou mesmo um CSV, que apesar de ser incremental e permitir o processamento "lazy" de linhas, não permite índices e queries.

O que é possível fazer nesse caso é: 
ler os dados do arquivo Excel anterior, e concatenar os dados novos ao final, em seguida gravar o arquivo de novo.

Ao final do seu programa dá pra fazer isso:

```py
from pathlib import Path  # a pathlib facilita trabalhar com arquivos

import csv

caminho = Path(r"C:\Users\nlsouza\Desktop\python5.xlsx")

if not caminho.exists():  
   # primeira execução - gravar conteúdo todo:
   tempo.to_excel(caminho)
else:
   dados_anteriores = pd.read_excel(caminho)
   novos_dados = pd.concat((dados_anteriores, tempo), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
   novos_dados.to_excel(caminho)
```

## Usando arquivos CSV

Se você deseja acrescentar dados *ao final* da sua tabela, a cada vez que o programa é executado, arquivos CSV podem ajudar. Mas não sentido pra isso nos dados que você extrai - pelo visto você quer só substituir os dados anteriores, não é? Daí é melhor a técnica de renomear o arquivo Excel mesmo.

Arquivos do tipo CSV podem sim ser aumentados ao final sem serem re-escritos: eles são arquivos textuais, e não tem "dados de fechamento": a sintaxe permite que sejam acrescentadas novas linhas ao final.

O problema é que o Pandas não tem suporte a isso - o método `.to_csv` do Pandas sempre vai escrever o arquivo inteiro de uma vez - e apagar o arquivo anterior.

Então é preciso ou usar o módulo "csv" do Python, ou, se fosse um dataframe mais complexo, usar o Pandas pra gerar um CSV temporário e copiar os dados para o CSV original usando alguma outra forma.

Dá pra fazer isso no final do seu programa então:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import csv

caminho = Path(r"C:\Users\nlsouza\Desktop\python5.xlsx")

if not caminho.exists():  
   # primeira execução - gravar cabeçalhos:
   with caminho.open("wt") as arq:
       writer = csv.writer(arq, delimiter=";")
       writer.writerow(tempo.columns)

with caminho.open("at") as arq:
   writer = csv.writer(arq, delimiter=";")
   for index, row in tempo.iterrows():
       writer.writerow(str(value) for value in row.values)
```

A grande desvantagem de usar um CSV em relação a um arquivo Excel, é que no CSV todos os dados são tratados como strings, e vai do programa que abrir o CSV (seja o Excel ou o próprio Pandas), "adivinhar" o tipo de dado de cada célula.
Se forem só números e strings de texto, em geral funciona direto - se você tiver dados como Datas, pode dar mais trabalho.  (E, se você quer realmente concatenar esses dados, incluir a data de quando o programa foi executado parece ser uma boa ideia).